# Network unreachable - MSSQL

Tags: linux, networking, ms-sql

I am trying to connect remotely to a sql server 2008.

I am able to make the connection with the local ip address (I am doing so from terminal in a linux os connected to the local network, using freetds), and everything works.

What I am trying to do is to access the database from a completely separate system, not connected to the local network. I am trying (and failing) to connect to the server when I try to access it by its public ip, which I get from here (SQL Server Configuration Manager->  SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for SQLEXPRESS -> TCP/IP) - the photo is illustrative, in my system the ip is enabled:

[image]

When I try to ping it, using `ping6 <my_ip> 1433`, I get the following error:

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Here are some useful information:

- Remote connections are allowed on the server.
- TCP/IP is enabled
- The specific ip is enabled and active in SQL ServerConfiguration Manager, and TCP Port is set to 1433.
- I added an exception on firewall for TCP with port 1433 and all networks.
- I also added an exception of firewall for sqlservr.exe

Any ideas?

---

**Edit:** Ok, since the IPv6 I was using is not the correct IP (as pointed out, it is local, not public), how can I get the correct IP to use for connection? I searched about it, but all I got was how to find some local IPs.

Comment: Sounds like a routing issue with network routers or firewalls, etc. The traffic has to be routable across your network between subnets (or from your public interface e.g. port forwarding, or NAT) or it won't work so I'd get with your network administrators to confirm or see if they can help as it doesn't sound like a server level OS firewall issue.

Comment: Is this ip i'm using the right one? I'm worried it might not be, but I have no idea if it is.

Comment: Are you the network administrator on your network with these different networks you speak of as completely separate systems? I'd get with the network administrators on this first as they'd understand your network topology best. If you need to come from the outside world into this server, then I'm not sure you'd want to allow port 1433 into it and control that through some app configuration perhaps instead. It's hard telling what you need without more detail. I think it'd be best to talk with your data network staff first if you don't understand these aspects just in case.

Answer (score 1):

fe80:: is a IPv6 link-local address, so that's not a public IP. Those can be used within a network, but not across routers.

So if the fe80::... IP is the one you are using i'm positive it's not the right one to use.

Ah, also this makes little sense:

> ping6 < my_ip> 1433

because ping does not know about ports. Try using

$ telnet -6 <my_ip> 1433

instead, if you want to check the tcp connection.

As far as the error message is concerned

> connect: Network is unreachable

you will also get this message if your client host doesn't have IPv6 connectivity.

Try this on your client

```
$ telnet -6 google.com 80
```

and see if you get a connection or if you get Network unreachable.

Comment: I tried `telnet -6 google.com 80` and got network is unreachable. What does this mean?

Comment: It's either Roberto Alcantara is correct and you have no ipv6 default route, or your client does not have any IPv6 connectivity at all.

Comment: Try looking at the output of ip -6 route, should look like

2xxx:xxx:xxx:xxxx::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
(with lowercase hex numbers instead of the x's)

Comment: `ip -6 route` gave this output: `fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256`

Comment: fe80::/64 that's another link-local address, so not routeable over the internet, which is why it's working locally, but not from the separate system in another network.

Comment: Basically you don't have public IPv6 addresses, so you need to get those or get IPv4 addresses and use those.

Comment: I am not sure i need to use IPv6s at all, since the one i was using is apparently wrong. The problem is, how can I get the IP I need to use here in order to connect to sql server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34607/discussion-between-gabriel-ilharco-and-remote-mind).

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are without default route.

Check it with

```
# ip -6 route
```

You should see something like this:

```
default via 2801:95:1f0:::1 dev bond0  metric 1  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
```

Now you can ping6 this IP address (default gateway) and check your ipv6 local connectivity. If your default route is a link-local address (fe80::) you need to put -I  on ping6 to specify the ethernet device used.

It this is ok try to

```
tracepath6 www.google.com
```

to check where you are stopping.

Comment: `tracepath6 www.google.com` gave the following output: `1: send failed` `Resume: pmtu 128000`

Comment: Seems you have IPv6 connectivity issue. What about default route?